# How to replace the first line of a CSV string (headers) with a list of values

Tags: python, csv

Given:

- list of strings: `headers`,
- CSV string: `data`
- Mapping object: `map`

What is the best way to rename the elements of the first row of CSV data according to the values in headers, as defined by the key:values in a mapping object?

headers: `['a','b','c']`

data:

```
1,2,3
xxx,yyy,zzz
jjj,kkk,lll
```

map:

```
{
   "1":"a",
   "2":"b",
   "3":"c"
}
```

Desired result:

```
a,b,c
xxx,yyy,zzz
jjj,kkk,lll
```

Comment: The best way? - *One that works*

Comment: `1,2,3,` - is there really a comma at the end?

Comment: Typo, will update. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Best way* is often subjective... It depends on the size of the file, whether Pandas is already installed and used, etc.

Using Pandas:

```
with io.StringIO() as out:
    pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data)).rename(columns=map).to_csv(out)
    newdata = out.getvalue()
```

Using `split` (if the header line is trivially simple like in the example):

```
with io.StringIO(data) as fdin, io.StringIO() as fdout:
   print(','.join(map.get(i,i) for i in next(fdin).strip().split(',')), file=fdout)
   for line in fdin:
       fdout.write(line)
   newdata = fdout.getvalue()
```

Using the csv module (if the header line could contain complex fields with newlines of commas inside them):

```
with io.StringIO(data) as fdin, io.StringIO() as fdoutheader, io.StringIO as fdout:
    csv.writer(fdoutheader).writerow(next(csv.reader(io.StringIO(next(fdin)))))
    for line in fdin:
        fdout.write(line)
    newdata = fdoutheader.getvalue + fdout.getvalue()
```

With more decompositions and comment if readability is important:

(left to the reader as an exercise...)

Etc.

Comment: Many thanks for providing options. Does the pandas option represent increased resource overhead?

Comment: Of course yes. Pandas is a very powerful tool and loads a good deal of code, including the excellent numpy library. It is really a must have, when processing large datasets with various statistics on them, but installing and learning it for a trivial task is probably overkill.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way if you are reading the values in dataframe

```
  df.columns =  ['a','b','c']
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help i guess

```py
# df is the dataframe of your csv

map = {
   "1":"a",
   "2":"b",
   "3":"c"
}

list_ = df[0].tolist()
for i, ele in enumerate(list_):
    df[0][i] = map[ele]
```

Comment: Thank you - if possible, I'd like to achieve this without pandas

Comment: Yeah so how are you going to read csv file? Then I can change the code accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Use the mapping to make a translation table then translate the header.

```
import io
data='''1,2,3
xxx,yyy,zzz
jjj,kkk,lll'''

d = {
    "1":"a",
    "2":"b",
    "3":"c"
    }
tbl = str.maketrans(d)

data = io.StringIO(data)
out = io.StringIO()

hdr = next(data)
out.write(hdr.translate(tbl))
out.write(data.read())
#out.seek(0)
```

This will only work for single character translations. `d={'12':'ab','34':'cd'}` would not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Python builtin `csv` module and a list comprehension:

```
import csv
mapping = {"1": "a", "2": "b", "3": "c"}
with open("replace_header.csv") as infile, open("replaced_header.csv", "w", newline="") as outfile:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=",")
    header = next(csv_reader)
    # replace header
    header = [mapping[col] for col in header]
    # write to new file
    csv_writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=",")
    csv_writer.writerow(header)
    for row in csv_reader:
        csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Thanks, I’d like to be able to complete the task in memory with reading to the file system.